# Is there a DatabaseLink for Hive?

Tags: interoperability, databases

I have a Hadoop based data warehouse with which and I typically use the command line or Hue to perform Hive queries. I was hoping there is a built-in library or third party connector for doing this directly from Mathematica? There's nothing in the docs on this.

Comment: No. I haven't seen anything and I probably would have. There is Hadoop-Link, but that's probably not useful.

Comment: @Searke: a quick search indicates that there is a JDBC driver for Hive, it might be worth to try to install that and configure DatabaseLink to use it. I do not know whether or how well that would work, but do you have indication that it won't work?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use an [R and Hive setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276487/connectivity-between-r-and-hive) and import data into Mathematica through [RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html).